# Matplot: How to plot true/false or active/deactive data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I want to plot a `true/false` or `active/deactive` binary data similar to the following picture:
[image: True/False Plot]

The horizontal axis is time and the vertical axis is some entities(Here some sensors) which is active(white) or deactive(black). How can I plot such a graphs using `pyplot`.

I searched to find the name of these graphs but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

What you are looking for is `imshow`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# get some data with true @ probability 80 %
data = np.random.random((20, 500)) > .2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(data, aspect='auto', cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
```

Then you will just have to get the Y labels from somewhere.

[image]

It seems that the image in your question has some interpolation in the image. Let us set a few more things:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create a bit more realistic-looking data
# - looks complicated, but just has a constant switch-off and switch-on probabilities
#   per column
# - the result is a 20 x 500 array of booleans
p_switchon = 0.02
p_switchoff = 0.05
data = np.empty((20,500), dtype='bool')
data[:,0] = np.random.random(20) < .2
for c in range(1, 500):
    r = np.random.random(20)
    data[data[:,c-1],c] = (r > p_switchoff)[data[:,c-1]]
    data[-data[:,c-1],c] = (r < p_switchon)[-data[:,c-1]]

# create some labels
labels = [ "label_{0:d}".format(i) for i in range(20) ]

# this is the real plotting part
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(data, aspect='auto', cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(labels)))
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
```

creates
[image]

However, the interpolation is not necessarily a good thing here. To make the different rows easier to separate, one might use colors:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import numpy as np

# create a bit more realistic-looking data
# - looks complicated, but just has a constant switch-off and switch-on probabilities
#   per column
# - the result is a 20 x 500 array of booleans
p_switchon = 0.02
p_switchoff = 0.05
data = np.empty((20,500), dtype='bool')
data[:,0] = np.random.random(20) < .2
for c in range(1, 500):
    r = np.random.random(20)
    data[data[:,c-1],c] = (r > p_switchoff)[data[:,c-1]]
    data[-data[:,c-1],c] = (r < p_switchon)[-data[:,c-1]]

# create some labels
labels = [ "label_{0:d}".format(i) for i in range(20) ]

# create a color map with random colors
colmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(np.random.random((21,3)))
colmap.colors[0] = [0,0,0]

# create some colorful data:
data_color = (1 + np.arange(data.shape[0]))[:, None] * data

# this is the real plotting part
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(data_color, aspect='auto', cmap=colmap, interpolation='nearest')
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(labels)))
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
```

creates

[image]

Of course, you will want to use something less strange as the coloring scheme, but that is really up to your artistic views. Here the trick is that all `True` elements on row `n` have value `n+1` and, and all `False` elements are `0` in `data_color`. This makes it possible to create a color map. Naturally, if you want a cyclic color map with two or three colors, just use the modulus of `data_color` in `imshow` by, e.g. `data_color % 3`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know the name of these kinds of graphs?

Comment: +1 seems that also the original was made using Matplotlib, looks exactly the same. For what it is worth, I find the use of interpolation misleading for this application, this suggest that there is a gradual transition between a fridge and a telephone! I would prefer straight bars, but maybe go for some nice colors instead.

Comment: @Constantine: I would call it a timeline plot, but I really do not know if there would be a better name. Ribbon plot is unfortunately reserved for something else.

Comment: @BasSwinckels: Yep, the interpolation is not the best thing here. I added a non-interpolated version with colors (dunno about the niceness of the colors). From the visualization point of view I would actually have three rows of data (color/dark color) and one empty row (black) between the different blocks, as that would make it visually easier to follow each row.

Comment: Seriously high quality answer. This deserves some kind of award.

Comment: `---> 15     data[-data[:,c-1],c] = (r < p_switchon)[-data[:,c-1]]`

The numpy boolean negative, the `-` operator, is not supported, use the `~` operator or the logical_not function instead.

Comment: data[data[:,c-1],c]  # what is this? Data indexed by an array slice of itself and the x-axis value?